# Is it possible to add new fields to the details of a file in Google Drive using the SDK?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, metadata

I would like to know whether it is possible to add new fields to the details of a file in Google Drive using the SDK.

[image]

The picture shows an example of a video file. I would like to add a new field with the duration of the video. Is there any method/class available for that?

Answer (score 1):

A [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) contains a large number of fields.   Is this what you are looking for.

```
 "videoMediaMetadata": {
    "width": integer,
    "height": integer,
    "durationMillis": long
  },
```

Note these fields do not appear to be writable but they may have been filed out when you upload the video in question.

Comment: My point is having a quick preview of the duration of the video without opening it, but it looks that it's not possible at all. 
I'll have a look to your solution, apparently it is possible to add custom properties to a file (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties).
Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: Indeed Custom File Properties can be quite useful,  I keep forgetting about them